# TypeError: this.model.toJSON is not a function

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I am getting the above title error in firebug. Not sure what can be the problem..

**My View**

```
app.View.TrendsView = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: _.template($('#trends-template').html()),

        render: function() {
            this.$el.empty();
            this.$el.html(this.template({
                trends: this.model.toJSON()
            }));
            return this.$el;
        }
    });
```

**calling**

```
app.views.trends = new app.View.TrendsView({ model : model });
```

**Firebug**

[image]

**My model creation**

```
      var m = new app.Model.TrendModel();
      m.url='/trends'
      m.set('login', login);
      m.save(null, {
        success: function(collection, model, response){
            app.views.trends = new app.View.TrendsView({
                model : model
            });
            $('#tab-content').empty();
            $('#tab-content').append(app.views.trends.render());
        },
        error: function(collection, model, response){
        }
      });
      m.destroy();
```

**Spring code**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/trends", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public TrendResultDTO getTrends(@RequestBody UserDTO user,
            HttpServletResponse response) {
```

Comment: Can you show where `model` is created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation on [`model.save`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save)

> `save` accepts `success` and `error` callbacks in the options hash, which
>   will be passed the arguments **`(model, response, options)`**

but the arguments your callbacks expect are `collection, model, response` which means you pass your response as model to your view, as demonstrated by your console log.

Try

```
m.save(null, {
    success: function(model, response, options){
        app.views.trends = new app.View.TrendsView({
            model : model
        });
        // ...
    },
    error: function(model, response, options){
    }
});
```